# Levy-Khintchine formula using stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

looking through Nicolas Privault's Introduction to Stochastic Finance with Market Examples, I ran into the following version of Levy-Khintchine formula:
$$
\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\int_0^T f(t) dY_t\right) \right] = \exp\left(\lambda \int_0^T \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(e^{yf(t)}-1)\nu(dy)dt\right). \tag 1
$$

Here $Y_t$ is a compound Poisson process defined as
$$
Y_t = \sum_{k=1}^{N_t}Z_k
$$
where $N_t$ is a simple Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$. Random variables $Z_k$ are independent, identically distributed, square-integrable and their probability distribution is $\nu(dy)$.

The book claims that formula $(1)$ follows as a consequence of the following proposition:
$$
\mathbb E[e^{\alpha(Y_T -Y_t)}] = \exp ((T-t)\lambda (\mathbb E[e^{\alpha Z_1}]-1)).
$$

It is not immediately clear how formula $(1)$ immediately follows from the above proposition. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does (1) become equal to that second formula for $f(u)=\alpha1_{[t,T]}(u)\,?$

Comment: @KurtG. sure it does. But I don't exactly see how to turn if the other way around..

Comment: Show first that (1) holds for all step functions $f\,.$